# Call signature error when using the scrollTop method in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like the cardSummary element to scroll to top when it is clicked. This is what I've applied so far:

```
public onClickHandler(event: React.MouseEvent<any>): void {
    if (this.props.onClick) {
        console.log("scroll");
        if (this.isInViewport(this._cardSummary) === false) {
            this._cardSummary.scrollTop(0);
            this.props.onClick(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I want to compile this, I get an error `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Number' has no compatible call signatures.`

What do I have to do to invoke the scrollTop method when the element is out of viewport?

Here is the component in its entirety:

```
export class CardSummary extends React.Component<ICardSummaryProps, undefined> {
    public static defaultProps = { labelColor: "transparent" };

    private _cardSummary: HTMLDivElement;

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return <div className="card-summary" onClick={this.onClickHandler.bind(this)} ref={(el) => this._cardSummary = el } >
            <div>
                <div className="color" style={{ "backgroundColor": this.props.labelColor, flexShrink: 0, "float": "left" }}></div>
                <div className="row card-rowcontainer">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }

    public isInViewport(element: boolean) {
        const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        const html = document.documentElement;
        return (
            rect.top >= 0 &&
            rect.left >= 0 &&
            rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || html.clientHeight) &&
            rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || html.clientWidth)
        );
    }

    public onClickHandler(event: React.MouseEvent<any>): void {
        if (this.props.onClick) {
            console.log("scroll");
            if (this.isInViewport(this._cardSummary) === false) {
                this._cardSummary.scrollTop(0);
                this.props.onClick(event);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `_cardSummary`?

Comment: _cardSummary is a HTMLDivElement

Comment: `scrollTop()` is a jQuery method. On a DOM element it is just a property that returns the scroll position. Did you mean to use jQuery or `window.scrollTo`?

Comment: let me try something with window.scrollTo

Comment: You can also try assigning: `this._cardSummary.scrollTop = 0`

Comment: Thanks, I'm also going to try this: this._cardSummary.window.scrollTo(0, 0);

Comment: Strangely enough, it accepted this._cardSummary.scrollTop = 0; No compile errors now. Going to see if behavior is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you include dom types on lib inside tsconfig.json:

```
"target": "es5",
"lib": [
  "dom",
  "es5",
  "scripthost"
],
```

Note if your targe is es5 your default included libs should be don, es5 and scripthost, so, you should be well covered.

Try that, if not, please share your tsconfig.